# Optimizing nested for loops

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel workbooks - wb1 and wb2. wb1 has a single sheet. wb2 has multiple sheets each with a fraction of data from wb1. I need to compare wb1 with wb2 to check if wb1 has all the data from wb2. The data from each row of the two workbooks can be compared with a key. If the rows in wb1 and wb2 have the same key, they can be compared. I'm using nested for loops to implement this and this approach works for me but it takes too long to go through all the rows. I'm looking for a more efficient way. I appreciate any help for this.

I used nested for loops to compare the sheets in workbooks.

Loop 1 - loop through the wb1 worksheet rows

Loop 2 - loop through the wb2 worksheets. Taking each worksheet to compare with the wb1 worksheet

Loop 3 - loop through wb2 worksheet rows. Check if the key value matches

Loop 4 - loop through the wb1 worksheet column length

Loop 5 - loop through the wb2 worksheet column length. Compare if the column names in wb1 and wb2 match

```
For i = 2 To wb1Length 
    Found = False
    For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets 'Loop through all the sheets in actual workbook
        ws2Length = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ws2colLength = ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For j = 2 To ws2Length 'Loop through one actual worksheet rows
            If ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value = ws2.Cells(j, "A").Value Then 
             
                
                For a = 2 To expectedcolLength 
                    expectedAttribute = ws1.Cells(1, a).Value
                        
                        For b = 2 To ws2colLength
                            actualAttribute = ws2.Cells(1, b).Value
                            
                            If ExtractedExpectedAttribute = actualAttribute Then 
                                 // comparision
```

Comment: Reading/writing cells can be a bottleneck for performance. Loading data into an array and manipulating it in memory can significantly improve efficiency. If you share some sample data, SO users might be able to optimize the comparison logic.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be much faster.  Working with arrays and using `Match` in place of nested loops.

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant, ws2 As Worksheet, ws2Length As Long, ws2colLength As Long
    Dim j As Long, id, ws1 As Worksheet, wb2 As Workbook, wb1Length As Long, a As Long
    Dim mId As Variant, mHdr As Variant, arrMain As Variant, expectedcolLength As Long
    
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet 'for example
    arrMain = WorksheetData(ws1)
    
    '...
    '...set wb2
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrMain, 1) 'loop rows
        
        id = arrMain(i, 1) 'read this *once*, but ideally you're using an array....
        
        For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets 'Loop through all the sheets in wb2
            
            arr = WorksheetData(ws2)
           
            mId = Application.match(id, ws2.Columns("A"), 0) 'Match is fast
            If Not IsError(mId) Then
                For a = 2 To UBound(arrMain, 2) 'loop headers
                    mHdr = Application.match(arrMain(1, a).Value, ws2.rows(1), 0)
                    If Not IsError(mHdr) Then
                        'compare arrMain(i,a) to arr(mId,mHdr)
                    End If
                Next a
            End If
        Next ws2
    Next i
End Sub

'return worksheet data as 2D array (assumes regular table starting at A1)
Function WorksheetData(ws As Worksheet) As Variant
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    WorksheetData = ws.Range("A1").Resize(lr, lc).Value
End Function
```